# How to prevent a user from booking an existing appointment in a sql data in asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

Here is my appointment controller where I have create appointment code what can I add here so if the user books an appointment on the same time as another user it doesn't allow them to book it

```
public class AppointmentController : Controller
{
    Context db = new Context();

    // GET: Appointment
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string UserName = User.Identity.Name;
        return View(db.Appointment.ToList().Where(a=> a.username == UserName));
    }


    public ActionResult Create()
    {


        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Appointment appointment)
    {
        try{
            string UserName = User.Identity.Name;
            appointment.username = UserName;
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
           // if (ModelState.IsValid)
           // {
                db.Appointment.Add(appointment);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Appointment");
           // }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an ASP MVC Controller.  MVC is generally faster to develop for once you get the hang of it, but the learning curve is steep.

There are many MVC tutorials available, such as [MVC 5 Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

For your original question, the below may work:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Appointment appointment)
{
    //This action will receive a "Model" (the appointment object) from the View (WebPage).
    //Most "HttpPost" methods are attempting to Save data in some way: Update, Create, etc. 
    //The general flow in an MVC Post method is
    //1. Check that the Model is Valid (required fields have a value, numbers don't have letters, etc.)
    //2. Then perform any server side checks (like conflicting schedules)
    //3. Then attempt to save.
    //4. If successful, return to Index. Else, add the Error to the Model and return the Model.

    try{

        //Use LINQ to check if the Appointment the User wants to book
        // 1. Starts before any other appointment ends 
        // 2. AND ALSO Ends after any other appointment starts.
        // If both conditions are true, there is some overlap
        // Making a guess as to what the fields representing Start and Stop times are called.
        // Replace the field names as appropriate
        if (db.Appointment.Where(a => a.EndTime > appointment.StartTime && a.StartTime < appointment.EndTime).Any()) 
            //If any existing appointment exists, then add a model state error.
            ModelState.AddModelError("StartTime", "Time not available.");

        //Using the Logged In User's UserName as the appointment's UserName
        appointment.username = User.Identity.Name;

        //TODO: Add in any other checks or changes here.
        //Example: Check if the appointment is within business hours.
        //They will follow the same format:
        //   Check the Condition
        //   If something is wrong, add the ModelError to the ModelState.

        //If a field is invalid, or we added a ModelError, the ModelState will NOT be valid.
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Add a row to the appointment table.
            db.Appointment.Add(appointment);

            //Save the change.
            db.SaveChanges();

            //Send the user back to Index.
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Appointment");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Returns a detailed error message to the User.
        //While helpful for development, this is generally a no-no in production.
        return View(ex.ToString());
    }

    //Return the appointment model back to the View.
    //The model will contain the ModelError, which will trigger
    // any validation code on the View.
    return View(appointment);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

this is a very amateur way of coding i will suggest you compare it with java with a if statements. you need to grab the value and send it to the database and compare it with the value. But like i said i will rethink this code because this is an inefficient way of coding and not the right way.

goodluck

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, I am a beginner to C# so my skills are not up to scratch. I can replicate this in another language such as PHP. I would be really thankful If you can provide me with any resources or provide an idea of what I am missing in this code I would really appreciate it.

Comment: From seeing your code i believe you are able to do what you have asked. By you asking this questions it seems like you have not coded this yourself  because it is very simple. i will rethink the language you are coding in, if i was you i will look at this link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54636/input-validation-for-text-boxes-in-a-form

hopefully this link helps you but please rethink your language.